# Random genera 2 números iguales

Tags: c#, .net, random

tengo un problema algo curioso que ya he resuelto pero me gustaría que me ayudaran a saber el por qué.
Tengo 2 métodos, dentro de ellos instancio a la clase Random y luego la uso para generar un número aleatorio en cada uno de ellos, en el primer método con 10 dígitos y en el segundo con 2, la cuestión es que en ambas devoluciones siempre coinciden los primeros 2 dígitos y no se por qué. Lo he solucionado instanciando a la clase fuera de los métodos. Pero me gustaría saber por qué esto solucionó mi problema, muchas gracias.

Estoy usando .NET framework 4.8

```
private string Generar1()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int i, numero;
        string generado1 = "";

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numero = rnd.Next(10);

            generado1 += numero.ToString();
        }
        return generado1;
    }

    private string Generar2()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int i, numero;
        string generado2 = "";

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            numero = rnd.Next(10);

            generado2 += numero.ToString();
        }
        return generado2;
    }
```

Comment: que version de net framework o .net core estas usando?

Comment: No sé por qué dices que no funciona. Copié tu código y esta fue la salida.
`Generar 1 =6369801701 - Generar 2 = 1031444874` .
`Generar 1 =5870364417 - Generar 2 = 6244328520` .
`Generar 1 =7168487673 - Generar 2 = 9089725169`

Comment: @Arriel la clase Random en .net framework y en .net core funcionan diferente. En .net core no hay este problema

Comment: Hola, estoy usando .NET framework 4.8
Y sí, efectivamente en .NET Core no sucede esto, pero en Framework si :/

Comment: ¿Seguro que no es una mera casualidad?

Comment: Hola, no es mera casualidad, al crear dos objetos de la clase `Random` te va a suceder eso siempre, te van a dar los mismos núemros, y si esa es la solución, siempre que necesites números aleatorios usa el mismo objeto, Saludos

Comment: @rene Muchas gracias!